# Theme Remover Script

Tags: terminal

This is my script. Its permissions are set to 755.

```
#!bin/bash


echo "Deleting the themes you don't want!"

sleep 2

echo  "                 by D3@TH from Deaths Repo"

##### root test #####
# won't go any farther unless you're uid=0
[ `id -u` != 0 ] && exec echo "Oops, you need to be root to run this script"

echo ".....removing WinterBoard Default Themes!"

echo "…..now deleting themes!"

cd /Library/Themes/
rm -rf Black Navigation Bars.theme Dim Icons.theme Dim Wallpaper.theme No Docked Icon Labels.theme No Undocked Icon Labels.theme Solid Status Bar.theme Transparent Dock.theme User Lock Background.theme User Wallpaper.theme White Icon Labels.theme
sleep 2

echo ".....moving themes to var"

mv /Library/Themes /private/var/ && ln -s /private/var/WinterBoard /Library/Themes
echo "Finished deleting the themes you didn't want feel free to delete me I don't mind."

sleep 3

apt-get remove net.death.themeremover

killall WinterBoard

exit 0
```

Every time I try running this on my iPhone or iPod, I get this:

> -sh: /usr/bin/winterboard: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Is there anyway of fixing this I'd like to be able to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

The first line should read:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Note the leading forward slash, which will make it relative to the root of the filesystem instead of the current directory.

Comment: Ok I fixed that but it's not deleting the folders in that directory like it should

Comment: That's part of another question, I think. Anyway, try quoting the directory names.

Comment: Well each folder ends with .theme so I need it to move the folders listed into a different directory where it don't delete it completely in case they decide they want those themes back they can go to that directory and get them

Comment: @user1493681: Quote them, really.

Comment: I did a complete rewrite of the script and it works the way I want it thanks guys for the help